# Passing class instance in the method argument

Tags: python

I am learning OOP, have hard time grasping how to different classes interact with each other. I read so many examples but majority of them show how single class works, and that's clear, I want to see how different classes to interact among themselves. If someone has a good example how different classes interact it would be great.

Here I create `Deck` instance `newDeck` and then `Player` instance `p1`. Then I do this:
`newCard.append(player.generateCard(newDeck))` where `player` is `p1`, so I call `Player` method `generateCard()` and pass `newDeck` instance of class `Deck`. Is this allowed?

Here I get error:

```
   File "poker.py", line 67, in startGame
    newCard.append(player.generateCard(newDeck))
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'generateCard'`
```

My code:

```
import random, string, sys

class Deck:
    def __init__(self):
        self.suits = ['s', 'h', 'd', 'c']
        self.ranks = ['2', '3', '4', '5', '6' ,'7', '8', '9', '10', 'J', 'Q', 'K', 'A']
        self.deck = [i+j for i in self.ranks for j in self.suits]
        random.shuffle(self.deck)

    def selectCards(self):
        self.selectedCard = self.deck.pop()
        return self.selectedCard

class Player:
    def __init__(self, amount):
        self.amount = amount
        self.card = []

    def generateCard(self, whichDeck):
        self.whichDeck = whichDeck
        holeCards = 2
        for i in range(0, holeCards):
            selCard = self.whichDeck.selectCards()
            if len(selCard) == 2:
                self.cardRank = list(selCard[0])
            else:
                self.cardRank = list('10') 
            self.cardSuit = list(selCard[-1])
            self.generatedCard = list(self.cardRank + self.cardSuit)
            self.card.append(self.generatedCard)
        return self.card 

class Game:
    def __init__(self, numPlayers, startingStack):
        self.startingStack = startingStack
        self.numPlayers = numPlayers

    def startGame(self):
        newDeck = Deck()
        playerList = ['p1', 'p2', 'p3', 'p4', 'p5', 'p6', 'p7', 'p8']
        currentPlayer = 0
        for player in playerList:
            player = Player(self.startingStack)
            currentPlayer += 1 
            if currentPlayer == self.numPlayers:
                break
        totalPlayers = currentPlayer
        # -------------------------- GAME STARTS ---------------------------
        newCard = []
        currentPlayer = 0
        for player in playerList:                
            newCard.append(player.generateCard(newDeck)) # ERROR IS HERE               
            if currentPlayer == self.numPlayers:
                break

def main():
    numberOfPlayers = 1
    playerStack = 100
    newGame = Game(numberOfPlayers, playerStack)    
    newGame.startGame()
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: `player` is *not* a `Player` instance; it is a string.

Comment: Wait, but using the for loop I created `Player` instance with `p1`, so why I can't again use method of `Player` with same `p1`?

Comment: You never stored those `Player` objects anywhere; the `playerList` object is not updated.

Comment: You misunderstand Python assignment; see e.g. [here](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html) for an explanation of names in Python.

Comment: Yes, agree, will read that one :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not have any `Player` instances, you create list of `string`s:

```
playerList = ['p1', 'p2', 'p3', 'p4', 'p5', 'p6', 'p7', 'p8']
```

then in the loop you just do

```
for player in playerList:
        player = Player(self.startingStack)
        currentPlayer += 1 
        if currentPlayer == self.numPlayers:
            break
```

and this **local** variable `player` is lost, it is not magically appended to your `playerList`

Simply do something like

```
playerList = [ Player(self.startingStack) for _ in range(self.numPlayers) ]
```

instead of your loop

Comment: Why did you delete `[ Player(0) for _ in range(self.numPlayers) ]`? This actually works perfectly, now everything works!

Comment: I moved it to the end of the answer to make it more complete

Comment: Now I get it, your list comprehension example made it easy understandable :)

Answer (score 0):

Your `playerList` object is *still* a list of strings. Your loop:

```
for player in playerList:
    player = Player(self.startingStack)
    currentPlayer += 1 
    if currentPlayer == self.numPlayers:
        break
```

re-binds `player` to a `Player()` instance, but *this doesn't change the `playerList` object*. In fact, by the time you get to the next iteration, the `Player()` instance is discarded again as nothing else references it.

The `for player in playerList` binds `player` to each string in the list in turn, but the reference does not work the other direction, `player` is *just* another Python name, another reference to the same object contained *in* `playerList`. Assigning a different object to it will not also alter the list from which the strings were taken.

You probably wanted to build a new list here:

```
def startGame(self):
    newDeck = Deck()
    playerList = ['p1', 'p2', 'p3', 'p4', 'p5', 'p6', 'p7', 'p8']
    players = []
    for player in playerList[:self.numPlayers]:
        player = Player(self.startingStack)
        players.append(player)
    totalPlayers = self.numPlayers
    # -------------------------- GAME STARTS ---------------------------
    newCard = []
    for player in players:           
        newCard.append(player.generateCard(newDeck))
```

However, you are entirely ignoring the strings in `playerList` here; may as well just build the list without consulting those:

```
def startGame(self):
    newDeck = Deck()
    players = [Player(self.startingStack) for _ in range(self.numPlayers)]
    newCard = [player.generateCard(newDeck) for player in players]
```

but you don't need `players` then as a separate list either:

```
def startGame(self):
    newDeck = Deck()
    newCard = [Player(self.startingStack).generateCard(newDeck)
               for _ in range(self.numPlayers)]
```

Comment: Now I understand my problem, and you are right about last point. Thank you for making it clear for me.

Comment: And I made code much shorter, I had so much useless stuff apparently.